# What is the equivalent of request_processors in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, full-page-cache

Anyone know where the equivalent of `request_processors` is in Magento 2?  In Magento 1 this was used in EE being defined in `app/etc/enterprise.xml` - it was the starting point for loading FPC content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that there doesn't appear to an equivalent in Magento 2, the built in FPC instead uses plugins to intercept the request and this happens at a much later point in the request cycle.  Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be anything nearly as early as `request_processors`, but I would imagine that was a deliberate choice by the core team due to the difficulties in accessing the system and data before the framework has been initialised.